MySQL. Будто не видит таблицу

При создании FK будто не видит таблицу employess, но если делать FK в таблце employess, то все работает исправно, что может быть не так?
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `personal_number` int NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `commission_rate` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT '3.00',
  `post` enum('директор','консультант','молодший продавець','старший продавець','закупник') DEFAULT NULL,
  `hire_date` date DEFAULT (curdate()),
  PRIMARY KEY (`personal_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id_order` int NOT NULL,
  `id_book` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_customer` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `paid` enum('Так','Ні') DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_order` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`),
  KEY `id_book_idx` (`id_book`),
  KEY `id_customer_idx` (`id_customer`),
  CONSTRAINT `id_book1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_book`) REFERENCES `book` (`id_book`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `id_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`id_customer`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id_customer`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `delivery` (
  `id_delivery` int NOT NULL,
  `id_book` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_provider` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_delivery` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_delivery`),
  KEY `id_book_idx` (`id_book`),
  KEY `id_provider_idx` (`id_provider`),
  CONSTRAINT `id_book` FOREIGN KEY (`id_book`) REFERENCES `book` (`id_book`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `id_provider` FOREIGN KEY (`id_provider`) REFERENCES `provider` (`id_provider`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `provider` (
  `id_provider` int NOT NULL,
  `name_provider` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_provider` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_provider` char(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_provider`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id_book` int NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_book` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publishing_office` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_book`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id_customer` int NOT NULL,
  `name_customer` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_customer` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_customer` char(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_customer`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci



Ничего не понятно. Добавьте в вопрос больше подробностей со скриптами, ошибками и так далее. Скрипты и ошибки должны быть текстом, скрины допустимы для дополнения

ALTER TABLE order ADD COLUMN placed_order INT NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN quantity INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, ADD CONSTRAINT placed_order_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (placed_order) REFERENCES employees (personal_number) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (book.#sql-1140_9, CONSTRAINT placed_order_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (placed_order) REFERENCES employees (personal_number) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
Но только что каким-то магическим образом все заработало, но спасибо, что не проигнорили :)

Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails Была попытка вставить запись со значением реферального поля, отсутствующим в референсной таблице.
